# Changing the state of a parent component using a function in the child compontent

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and I decided to build something simple like a Calculator to practice it's basics. However I have some trouble to understand the logic behind the information flow, and either there is a way for a child component to do the logic and update the parent in a natural way.

For example this is the basic structure of my calculator:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="calculator-main">
                <Screen numberOnScreen={this.state.numberOnScreen}/>
                    <NumberButton number={7} />
                    <NumberButton number={8} />
                    <NumberButton number={9} />
                    <OperatorButton operator="plus" view="-"/>
                ....
            </div>
        )
    }
}   


class Screen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="screen">{new Intl.NumberFormat().format(this.props.numberOnScreen)}</div>
        );
    }
};

class NumberButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const zeroClass = this.props.number === 0 ? " zero" : "";
        return (
            <button type="button" className={"number" + zeroClass}>{this.props.number}</button>
        );
    }
};
```

So I know that:

- I can create the functions inside Calculator and pass it as a prop to
  the buttons components, and call it onClick. (But it just feel weird).
- Create an event listener in the Calculator compontent, create the
  function inside the button component and pass the value via the event
  trigger; (But it feels artificial).
- Use some kind of global store?

But is there no natural react way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'natural'? I thought the natural way for react is to pass it the function from parent component to the children components, as mentioned in the article here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Yes, I know that this is the logic behind React, however it feels messy to declare all my function in the parent component, rather in the buttons components... So my question is basically, is "that's it" and you need to work with that flow, or is there a 'react' way to put your logic inside the child components and update the parent's state.

Comment: Technically, you can use state management library like redux or flux to store the state of the parent component and write the logic to change its state in the child component, so you don't have to write any logic in parent component.

Comment: To what is worth, I believe it is much more rewarding to learn react+redux than just react alone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know about React component communication. Here, I have implemented Child to Parent communication.

In this case Parent's state and state change method passes to child component through props. Then child can change parent's state use this method.

[React Component Communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication)

```
//Parent component

class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content: 'Initial Content'
        }
        this.changeContent = this.changeContent.bind(this);
    }

    changeContent(event){
        this.setState({
            content: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){
        let { content } = this.state;
        return <div>
             <Child content={content} changeContent={this.changeContent}/>
             <h1>{content}</h1>
         </div>
    }
} 

 // Child component

 class Child extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
     } 

     render(){
         let { content, changeContent } = this.props;
         return <input value={content} onChange={changeContent}/>
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, thought I did mention i'm aware of that option :) I just don't like how you need to implement the logic inside the parent. I think that i'll just have to rely on redux or similar library as D-reaper suggested.

Comment: This example has local state. Do you want to move state to redux? If you want to move state to redux I change my example with redux.